# Word for acts of leadership

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I'm working on a leadership concept that leadership is not about one heroic act, but rather the sum of lots and lots of smaller acts of leadership.  What word might I use to describe these smaller acts of leadership which are individually small but collectively powerful?

Comment: You can try "initiatives" .

Comment: Not really individual acts, but **habits** might be a useful word.

Comment: Something related to _[inspiration](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/inspiration)_?

Comment: Edison said it: "Genius is one percent inspiration, ninety-nine percent perspiration."